# How to return specific objects from json (case insensitive)?

Tags: javascript

I'm making an app with Express, Postgres and Sequelize.

I have a json that looks like this:

```
{
  "names": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "John",
      "surname": "Smith"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Peter",
      "surname": "Black"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Marie",
      "surname": "White"
    }
  ]
}
```

If I write one of their names in the query, case insensitive, I would like to return the whole element.

For example, if I query `mari` I want to return:

```
{
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Marie",
  "surname": "White"
}
```

Like this I managed to get only the value, but not the whole entry (I need the id)

```
const names = persons.map(a => a.name);
const surnames = persons.map(a => a.surname);
const namesSurnames = names.concat(surnames)
const el = namesSurnames.find(a => a.includes(req.query.keyword));
console.log('el:', el);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `.filter` method and use `.toLowerCase()` and `includes` to search for let's say the keyword `mari` in the name or surname key.

```js
const sample = {
  "names": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "John",
      "surname": "Smith"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Peter",
      "surname": "Black"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Marie",
      "surname": "White"
    }
  ]
};

const query = 'mari';
const name = sample.names.filter((user) => {
  return user.name.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase()) || user.surname.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase());
});

if (name.length > 0) {
  console.log(name[0]);
} else {
  console.error('NO NAME FOUND!');
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to check for the surname in the same line?

Comment: You want to check if the query is in the name or surname?

Comment: I want to check both

Comment: Updated my post @Al-josh. Just use OR